# Rails asset-url works but not asset-path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass

I am new to Rails and learning as I go.

I am trying to add fonts to my sass and **asset-url** works, the font is displayed, but returns the full path.

I am trying to use relative paths but when I try **asset-path** the font no longer works.

I have tried setting **config.action_controller.asset_host = nil** and even removing it entirely but it changes nothing.

Any help is appreciated.

**---UPDATE---**

I was able to confirm that both **font_path** and **font_url** output correctly in one of the template files.

**font_path =>** /assets/primary/primary-reg-webfont.woff

**font_url =>** http://0.0.0.0:3000/assets/primary/primary-reg-webfont.woff

So within my stylesheet I have the following:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Primary';
  src: font-path('primary/primary-reg-webfont.woff') format('woff'), 
       font-path('primary/primary-reg-webfont.woff2') format('woff2');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

which does **not** work, no errors just the font does not load.

Using:

```
src: font-url('primary/primary-reg-webfont.woff') format('woff'), 
     font-url('primary/primary-reg-webfont.woff2') format('woff2');
```

does work however I need it to function with relative paths and not absolute.

Comment: can you paste your sass file and config/application.rb file?

Comment: This is a team project that I should not be sharing too much from I believe. I will update above with a bit more detail though.

Comment: use `(asset-path(' ... '))` so that Rails creates the proper path for you. Refer https://gist.github.com/anotheruiguy/7379570

Comment: need to add `url` before asset path : `src: url(asset-path('my-font.woff'))`